# View HDF5 inside matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, hdf5

Just how good is MATLAB in opening and viewing HDF5 files? I can see there are a couple of `h5...` commands but I'm wondering if there is a way to "view" the file interactively as you could do with a `.mat` file or like `HDFView` tool?

Comment: I'd guess [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/hdf5.html) sums up all there is

Comment: As of a few releases ago, `.mat` files are actually `hdf` files, just with a very particular layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use Matlab and we use HDF5 files.  We also use a lot of Fortran, and one of the reasons we use HDF5 is to store datasets which can be read and written both by Fortran and Matlab.  Matlab *vs* Fortran for HDF5 is a bit like Matlab *vs* Fortran for most things, the former is easier to use, lets you try out ideas quickly, and gives you much tighter integration between data and visualisation.  You may have your own views on Matlab *vs* your favourite compiled language.

Matlab provides a complete (maybe not entirely complete, but we haven't found any features of the HDF5 Fortran APIs that we want to use that Matlab doesn't provide) interface to HDF5.  When you view the document that @GuntherStruyf pointed you at, read to the bottom where you can find information about Matlab's low-level HDF5 access functions. You can do a lot with the high-level access functions alone, but not everything.  And if you are already used to the HDF5 API for Fortran/C/C++, taking the same approach in Matlab and ignoring the higher-level functions is easy enough.

But we do use HDFView too, it's an easy way to trawl through an HDF5 file and, within certain limitations, an easy way to quickly edit an HDF5 file.  You can, for instance, cut and paste from Excel to HDFView; perhaps more relevant you can cut and paste from Matlab's variable editor. Matlab doesn't quite provide that level of easiness for viewing HDF5 files.

To sum up:

- HDFView for viewing and interactive editing
- Matlab for programming for prototyping and rapid deployment
- Fortran/C/C++ for programming for heavy-lifting.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would second the the HDFView recommendation (perhaps a link to HDFView would be useful though).